# Add mean and variability to seaborn FacetGrid distplots

Tags: seaborn

What is the best way to add a point representing the mean (or another measure of central tendency) and a measure of variability (e.g., standard deviation or confidence interval) to each histogram in a seaborn FacetGrid?

The result should look similar to the figure shown [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/266#issuecomment-93864445), but with a mean/SD in each of the FacetGrid subplots. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200165/seaborn-overlaying-a-box-plot-or-mean-with-error-bars-on-a-histogram) is a related question for the non-FacetGrid case.

Comment: Probably helpful: https://seaborn.github.io/tutorial/axis_grids.html#mapping-custom-functions-onto-the-grid

Answer (score 4):

Based on @mwaskom's comment, here is one possible solution (using boxplot, analogous for pointplot):

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.set(font_scale=1.3)

def dist_boxplot(x, **kwargs):
    ax = sns.distplot(x, hist_kws=dict(alpha=0.2))
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    sns.boxplot(x=x, ax=ax2)
    ax2.set(ylim=(-5, 5))

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="sex")
g.map(dist_boxplot, "total_bill");
```

[image: "distplot plus boxplot"]

(Not sure why the `0.01` is shifted slightly rightwards...)