# How to add a mean and median line to a Seaborn displot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, histogram

Is there a way to add the mean and median to Seaborn's `displot`?

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g = sns.displot(
    data=penguins, x='body_mass_g',
    col='species',  
    facet_kws=dict(sharey=False, sharex=False)
)
```

[image]

Based on [Add mean and variability to seaborn FacetGrid distplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075915/add-mean-and-variability-to-seaborn-facetgrid-distplots), I see that I can define a `FacetGrid` and map a function. Can I pass a custom function to `displot`?

The reason for trying to use `displot` directly is that the plots are much prettier out of the box, without tweaking tick label size, axis label size, etc. and are visually consistent with other plots I am  making.

```
def specs(x, **kwargs):
    ax = sns.histplot(x=x)
    ax.axvline(x.mean(), color='k', lw=2)
    ax.axvline(x.median(), color='k', ls='--', lw=2)

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=penguins, col='species')
g.map(specs,'body_mass_g' )
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Using [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) directly is not recommended. Instead, use other figure-level methods like [`seaborn.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html)

  - [`seaborn.FacetGrid.map`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.map.html#seaborn.FacetGrid.map) works with figure-level methods.
  - [seaborn: Building structured multi-plot grids](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### Option 1

- Use `plt.` instead of `ax`.

  - In the OP, the `vlines` are going to `ax` for the `histplot`, but here, the figure is created before `.map`.

```py
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")
g = sns.displot(
    data=penguins, x='body_mass_g',
    col='species',  
    facet_kws=dict(sharey=False, sharex=False)
)

def specs(x, **kwargs):
    plt.axvline(x.mean(), c='k', ls='-', lw=2.5)
    plt.axvline(x.median(), c='orange', ls='--', lw=2.5)

g.map(specs,'body_mass_g' )
```

### Option 2

- This option is more verbose, but more flexible in that it allows for accessing and adding information from a data source other than the one used to create the `displot`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

# load the data
pen = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

# groupby to get mean and median
pen_g = pen.groupby('species').body_mass_g.agg(['mean', 'median'])

g = sns.displot(
    data=pen, x='body_mass_g',
    col='species',  
    facet_kws=dict(sharey=False, sharex=False)
)
# extract and flatten the axes from the figure
axes = g.axes.flatten()

# iterate through each axes
for ax in axes:
    # extract the species name
    spec = ax.get_title().split(' = ')[1]
    
    # select the data for the species
    data = pen_g.loc[spec, :]
    
    # print data as needed or comment out
    print(data)
    
    # plot the lines
    ax.axvline(x=data['mean'], c='k', ls='-', lw=2.5)
    ax.axvline(x=data['median'], c='orange', ls='--', lw=2.5)
```

### Output for both options

[image]

### Resources

- Also see the following questions/answers for other ways to add information to a seaborn FacetGrid

  - [Draw a line at specific position/annotate a Facetgrid in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67524391/7758804)
  - [Overlay a vertical line on seaborn scatterplot with multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67522407/7758804)
  - [How to add additional plots to a seaborn FacetGrid and specify colors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67611640/7758804)

Answer (score 3):

Here you can use `sns.FacetGrid.facet_data` to iterate the indexes of the subplots and the underlying data.

This is close to how `sns.FacetGrid.map` works under the hood. `sns.FacetGrid.facet_data` is a generator that yields a tuple `(i, j, k)` of row, col, hue index and the `data` which is a DataFrame that is a subset of the full data corresponding to each facet.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


pen = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

# Set our x_var for later use
x_var = "body_mass_g"

g = sns.displot(
    data=pen,
    x=x_var,
    col="species",
    facet_kws=dict(sharey=False, sharex=False),
)

for (row, col, hue_idx), data in g.facet_data():
    # Skip empty data
    if not data.values.size:
        continue

    # Get the ax for `row` and `col`
    ax = g.facet_axis(row, col)
    # Set the `vline`s using the var `x_var`
    ax.axvline(data[x_var].mean(), c="k", ls="-", lw=2.5)
    ax.axvline(data[x_var].median(), c="orange", ls="--", lw=2.5)
```

Which outputs:
[image: FacetGrid with overlayed vlines for mean and median]