# Recalculate and visualize percentile lines in each subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to subplot multiple curves and show the percentile for each subset. however, with my current code it only plots the percentile of the whole dataset, not for each sample.

[image]

Code:

```
sns.set_theme()
grid = sns.FacetGrid(hist, col='Region',   height=4.3, sharey=False, sharex=False, margin_titles=False, row= 'Surname')
grid = grid.map(sns.histplot, 'Age',kde=True)



def vertical_mean_line_survived(x, **kwargs):

    Q1=np.percentile(hist['Age'], 10)
    Q2=np.percentile(hist['Age'], 90)

    plt.axvline(Q1, color='r', linestyle='--')
    plt.axvline(Q2, color='r', linestyle='--')
    
    
grid.map(vertical_mean_line_survived, 'Age') 

grid.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You are using the `hist` variable in your percentile annotation function, when you should be using `x`. Take a look at the answers in [How to add a mean and median line to a Seaborn displot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67613774/3279716). [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) is a wrapper for FacetGrid with distribution plots